# Separate compilation

Tags: c++11

I am learning C++ by S. Lippman 5th edition book. I reached chapter 6 where I can't understand separate compilation. In book is written "As an example, assume that the definition of our fact function is in a file named
fact.cc and its declaration is in a header file named Chapter6.h. Our fact.cc
file, like any file that uses these functions, will include the Chapter6.h header. We’ll
store a main function that calls fact in a second file named factMain.cc. To
produce an executable file, we must tell the compiler where to find all of the code we
use. We might compile these files as follows:

$ CC factMain.cc fact.cc # generates factMain.exe or a.out

$ CC factMain.cc fact.cc -o main # generates main or
main.exe

Here CC is the name of our compiler, $ is our system prompt, and # begins a
command-line comment. We can now run the executable file, which will run our main
function"

Where I have to compile these files($ CC factMain.cc fact.cc # generates factMain.exe or a.out
)? I use Codeblocks 16.01. Thank you.

Comment: run the commands from a terminal or cmd

Answer (score 2):

The commands:

```
$ CC factMain.cc fact.cc # generates factMain.exe or a.out
```

or

```
$ CC factMain.cc fact.cc -o main # generates main or main.exe
```

are what you enter into your terminal to compile all the files that you specify in the command-line prompt (in your case factMain.cc and fact.cc).

The -o flag at the end of your second command signifies the name that your executable will have. (If you do not have a -o flag then the name of your executable will be a.out)

In order to find your executable, just look in your present working directory within terminal. 
The command for this is:

```
ls
```

You should find your executable listed amongst all the files that are in that working directory.